# Function inside click event needs 2 clicks to trigger

Tags: jquery

I have an `a` link with id `#searchBoxPop2`. Once its clicked, I want to trigger `#searchBoxPop2.toggle` function. My problem is I have to click twice on the link for the toggle to trigger. Can you guys please help this dirty script? Thanks a lot

```
  $('#searchBoxPop2').live('click', function () {
      if (!$('.header-wrapper-home').length) {
          $('div.right-block').show();

              $('#searchBoxPop2').toggle(
              function () {
              $('.detail-page-content').animate({
                  marginTop: "+=290px"
              }, 800)
          },
              function () {
              $('.detail-page-content').animate({
                  marginTop: "0px"
              }, 800);
          });
      }
      if ($('.header-wrapper-home').length) {
          $('.header-wrapper-home').slideToggle('slow');

      }
  });
```

Please let me know if you want me to explain the rest of the code and what Im going to do in detial.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ is deprecated in 1.9

Comment: what happens is that when you first click the `a` tag, you set its `toggle` event, and it gets fired with the second click. The `toogle` event is fired whenever you click the element, you don't need that `click` event you are setting. However, `toggle` as said by the previous commenter, is not longer used.

Comment: Thanks. @EdgarAllanPwn : Whats the best alternative to toggle?

Comment: You'll need to encode it manually using a counter with if/else or a switch. The format is quite simple once you've done it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the [toggle event function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was deprecated in jQuery 1.9.
Thus you need to use your own method to alternate calls. At first I was annoyed that a built in alternative didn't exist, but this method is more succinct. Especially since once you have the format down, it's easy to replicate to any other event call.

Here's a quick and dirty callback function I just wrote. There are probably better ways of accomplishing this but it's a good starting point:

```
function () {
    var number = 2; // the number of events you toggle through
    if (! window.toggle_counter )
        window.toggle_counter = 0;
    switch (window.toggle_counter) {
        case 0:
            // do some things
            break;
        case 1:
            // do other things
            break;
        // etc ..
    }
    window.toggle_counter = (window.toggle_counter + 1) % number;
}
```

Be aware that window.variable_name is global scope, so be wary of conflicts.